# Preventing QComboboxView from autocollapsing when clicking on QTreeView item

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I'm using python3 + PyQt5. In my program I have QCombobox and a QTreeView inside that combobox. The QCOmbobox default behavior is to hide the dropdown list when an item is clicked. However, in my case there is not a simple list inside it, but a TreeView. So when I'm clicking an Expand Arrow in it, QCombobox hides the view so I can not select an item
[image]

I have no any specific code here, just widget initialization. I know that there are signals and slots so my guess here is that combobox catches the item click event and wraps it in its own behavior. So I think I need to override some method but I'm not sure which exactly.

Comment: According to the image you show, you only want the popup to close if you click on the item child2, or rather those items that do not have children. I am right?

Comment: @eyllanesc that's right. but the popup closes automatically even if I click just arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must disable the item being selectable to the items that you do not want to be set in the QComboBox, for example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    for i in range(3):
        parent = model
        for j in range(3):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem("parent {}-{}".format(i, j))
            if j != 2:
                it.setSelectable(False)
            parent.appendRow(it)
            parent = it
    w.setModel(model)

    view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    w.setView(view)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A more elegant solution is to overwrite the flags of the model:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class StandardItemModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def flags(self, index):
        fl = QtGui.QStandardItemModel.flags(self, index)
        if self.hasChildren(index):
            fl &= ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        return fl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    model = StandardItemModel()
    for i in range(3):
        parent = model
        for j in range(3):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem("parent {}-{}".format(i, j))
            parent.appendRow(it)
            parent = it
    w.setModel(model)
    view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    w.setView(view)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: your solution is great, but it does not allow to choose parent items.  I want to be able to choose parent items, my problem is that when I click an arrow to expand a parent it gets selected

Comment: @SergeyMaslov You have to be clear, so I ask you the question and point out that if you wanted the items that do not have children are only selectable and you said yes.

Comment: I'm sorry for this misunderstanding. I got your question wrong

Comment: @SergeyMaslov you should indicate that it is not selectable only when the arrow is pressed.

Comment: yes. I need to be able to select both parent and child but not when I click the arrow. And the tricky thing here is to override arrow clicking method